# alternate phrase for 'satisfying the thirst'?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, single-word-requests

I am trying to compose a poetry. There is a line which goes like this - 'you are like a river that'll satisfy the the thirst of the sea/ocean ' . I want to know if there are alternative phrases for 'satisfy the thirst'. I have thought of quench the thirst but i am looking for a one word substitution or just a different phrase for it. Please tell me if there is any exact term for 'satisfying the thirst' or anything relative that can be used. Thank you.

Comment: When formulating a question like this, rather than asking for a "better" word/term (which is entirely subjective and "opinion-based"), instead ask for some "alternatives" for the original word/term.

Comment: And how exactly is "quench" NOT a "one-word substitution" for "satisfy"?

Comment: @Little Eva : you are right LittleEva. I will definitely keep it in mind from here on.

Comment: Siddesh, your OP has been placed on "HOLD" read the box and follow its directions. Try to edit the OP so as to avoid the "primarily opinion-based" judgment - change the title, get rid of the word "better", include some of the research you've done about this issue in your new edit. Good luck.

Comment: I've made changes and specified it in the edit note. Why is my question still on hold

Answer (score 5):

> **slake** verb: 3rd person present: slakes; past tense: slaked; past participle: slaked; gerund or present participle: slaking
>
> 1. quench or satisfy (one's thirst).
>      "***slake*** your thirst with some lemonade"
>
> *synonyms*: quench, satisfy, sate, satiate, relieve, assuage 
>   "we longed for a mountain spring to ***slake*** our thirst" see Google [slake](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=slake+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 1):

Quench

'you are like a river that'll quench the thirst of the sea/ocean'

Comment: In the text of his question, OP mentions that he's considered and rejected *quench* (though he hasn't told us why!).